What will happen if running this following C code?
printf("%d\n", (1 ? (int)1 : (double)1.1));

The result is not 1, but a random integer(runing on my wsl on Windows10). Such as
-2031766944

201011808

I find this issue when I want to realize a dynamic or overlapped variable using the following way:
typedef enum _DataType
{
    INT,
    DOUBLE
} DataType;

typedef union _Data
{
    int int_;
    double dou_;
} Data;

typedef struct _Number
{
    DataType datatype;
    Data data;
} Number;

Because C is static typing. The is no function to get the real value of Number. So I tried a macro function like this:
#define GETVAL(param) (((param).datatype == INT) ? (param).data.int_ : (param).data.dou_)

But it seems that the function can only return double types. And when I was debugging, I found the above question.

The type of 1 ? (int)1 : (double)1.1 is double. You need to print the value with "%f" or similar. See C11 6.5.15

Sory this is my typo, the number before ? should be 1. I have corrected it.

0 or 1 doesn't change anything

Your code mis-uses so-called "reserved identifiers".

Thank you @pmg very much, I have got the reason for this issue.

Both branches of the conditional operator needs to have the same type, or at least one type that can be converted to the other. In this specific case, the int value will be converted to the common type double. The result of x ? (int) 1 : double) 1.1 will be a double (x is irrelevant for this).

Thank you very much. I see.

Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers says: — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces. See also What does double underscore (__const) mean in C?

To begin with, the casts are completely pointless. The literal 1 is already int, 1.1 is already double.
The way ?: works is that balances the 2nd and 3rd operand to become the same type, as if they were the two operands participating in the usual arithmetic conversions - see Implicit type promotion rules. In plain English, the operand with the lower conversion rank - in this case int, is always converted implicitly to the type of the operand with higher conversion rank - in this case double. This happens no matter if the 2nd or 3rd operator is evaluated.
So what you are seeing is 1 converted to double, followed by a lie to printf telling it with %d that you are about to print an int while you are actually sending it a double. Resulting in nonsense output.
Writing "variant" unions like this is generally considered bad practice. But if you insist, you'll have to do something like a wrapper function returning data through a  void* parameter to a caller-allocated object:
void get_value (const Number* number, void* dst)
{
  switch(number->datatype)
  {
    case INT:    *(int*)   dst = number->data.int_; break;
    case DOUBLE: *(double*)dst = number->data.dou_; break;
  }
}

This kind of icky "old school" type-generic programming is best avoided. Consider if you can redesign all of this entirely, first by getting rid of the "variant" and from there use modern C mechanisms like _Generic and/or typeof.

Conversion rank is only for integer types. double does not have a conversion rank. When floating-point types are involved, the conversions are determined by the rules of the usual arithmetic conversions, not conversion ranks.

@EricPostpischil But implicitly, you get a conversion rank between floating point types and integers too, through the usual arithmetic conversions. It is not the formal C standard definition of conversion rank, but we still get long double > double > float > the integer conversion ranks. Anyway, it is better that those curious read about "the usual arithmetic conversions" in the link provided, the quote from the standard is pretty straight-forward reading.
